# Pusher\Pusher::__construct(): Argument #1 ($auth_key) must be of type string, null given,

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies

i have cloned my project from github when i try to composer install on laragon terminal i get this following error

> Pusher\Pusher::__construct(): Argument #1 ($auth_key) must be of type string, null given

my php these are my versions

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "hisorange/browser-detect": "^5.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
    "stancl/tenancy": "^3.4"
},
```

i tried composer update and composer dump-autoload i want to have all the dependices for my project please help

Comment: Have you tried to comment/ask author on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you are using the Pusher library and it is likely loaded as part of a service provider or something.

Whatever `.env` variable you have for Pusher is missing, which is causing the value to be null rather than a string.

If you add the values to your `.env` file, it should make the error go away.

Below is an example of what I mean you should add:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxx
PUSHER_KEY=xxx
PUSHER_SECRET=xxx
```

Comment: but as i mentioned i am cloning this project and these values are blank in my .env.example file ,Is it something related to my composer version ?@james

Comment: Blank values are null, I believe. Can you put a value against them in your `.env` file. Also, have you copied the `.env.example` into your `.env` file?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, and it got solved. Thanks!

Comment: That's great @arbaazkhan. Please accept and upvote the answer so others know this was the solution.